# How to Selenium test Django project that retrieves data through APIs?

Tags: django, selenium, integration-testing

I have a Django Project. I want to make end-to-end tests for it using Selenium.
It interacts with Other components (usually run through docker-compose) API and functions properly.

The Django Project and 'Other Components' are different repositories (obviously there are multiple 'other components')

Testing of parts that don't involve API calls, have been tested.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a continuous integration like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) to do your automated task like Selenium.

It's really easy to install localy and/or  to serve.

How to install Jenkins : [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/)

have a great day!